# How do I make a simple PHP API handler?

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, digital-ocean

I've written a basic API script in PHP using cURL - and successfully used a version of it on another API, this one is specifically to handle domain DNS management on DigitalOcean - and I can't send data?

### Prelude...

*I understand there is a PHP library available, I'm not after something that full featured or bloated with dependencies - just something small to use locally **and primarily to help me understand how RESTful API's work a little better in practice** - an educational exercise*

### The offending Code...

```
function basic_api_handle($key, $method, $URI, $data) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$key,
        'Content-Type: application/json')
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URI);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false) error_log("API ERROR: Connection failure: $URI", 0);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

var_dump(basic_api_handle($api_key, 'POST', 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains', array('name' => 'my-domain.tld', 'ip_address' => '1.2.3.4')));
```

This works with a GET request, such as listing the domains on the account but seems to fail at posting/sending data... this results in "unprocessable_entity" and "Name can't be blank" - as the name is not blank and is correctly formatted (as far as I can tell) it suggests to me the data is not being sent correctly?

### Solution Attempts so far...

I've tried json encoding the data (seen in code), not json encoding, url encoding with and without json encoding and various other options with no luck.

I've seen a few posts online about this exact same issue specifically with DigitalOcean's API (and a another) but no one had an explanation *(other than give up and use the library or something to that affect)*.

Using cURL directly from a terminal does work etc so there is nothing wrong with the API for creating a domain.

As far as I understand, the authentication is working, and the general setup works as I can list domains within the account, I just cant POST or PUT new data. I've been though the [API's documentation](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/) and can't see what I'm doing wrong, maybe some sort of wrong encoding?

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

**Edit:**
After *much* work and research even other simple API handlers do not work with Digital Ocean (such as https://github.com/ledfusion/php-rest-curl) - is there something this API in particular needs or am I missing something fundamental about API's in general?

Comment: Maybe you are missing this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: I don't think so as for an API like this you need to change the method from POST to others like GET and PUT

Comment: Hey! I just wanted to let you know you're not going crazy; this is a deceptively complicated problem! The popular "just set `CURLOPT_POST` isn't the answer, because PHP cURL does it automatically for you.(http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#108162)

Comment: I also thought your content-type might be corrupted by POSTFIELDS, because this from the docs: "Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded." But dumping the raw header suggests your first Header: content-type is NOT overwritten.

Comment: What I can't do for you is the next suggestion, which is, try catching your raw cURL request, and check that it's coming out as legit JSON. How? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348132/how-to-view-php-curl-request-body-like-curlinfo-header-out-for-headers?rq=1

Comment: You would be surprised how many times a simple and hard to diagnose issue causes the problems. Are you getting an error response from digital ocean or from the HTTP request?  Easiest way to tell is to give us a dump of curl_getinfo():

Comment: Reading your post again it seems you are in fact getting an error from digital ocean, not HTTP. I had a hard to find issue once because I was hitting a slightly wrong URL and the server was returning a 301 redirect. My HTTP client was following the redirect but dropping the post body on the redirect. Sometimes the answer is weird.  Try these two diagnostic steps: 1) show us a dump of curl_getinfo() and 2) try running the API call from the command line.  I have had the command line give me useful debugging info that PHP curl hides. To be specific, run it using curl from the command line.

Comment: I've been able to create a new domain using your code. You can use curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE) to get the HTTP response code of the POST operation. It should return 201 for a successful creation.

Comment: Tried your code and it just works.  The error is not a curl error but a digital ocean error, and maybe the error message is deceiving, you might want to check that your domain name is correct and that the IP address is also correct. If that fails, then maybe you want to check your computer and the curl version. Tested on PHP 7 with curl version = 7.0.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technically this is not an fix but a work around.** *Thank you everyone for your comments and ideas, unfortunately nothing worked/fixed the code and the bounty expired :(*

Although I have no idea why the PHP cURL option didn't work (the HTTP works, just Digital Ocean spitting errors for unknown reason linked to validation of the post data)...

I do have a new method that **DOES WORK** finally... (thanks to [jtittle post on the Digital Ocean Community forum](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-make-a-simple-php-api-handler-for-digital-ocean))

Just incase that link dies in the future... he's the working function using streams and file_get_contents and *not curl*...

```
<?php
function doapi( $key, $method, $uri, array $data = [] )
{
    /**
     * DigitalOcean API URI
     */
    $api = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2';

    /**
     * Merge DigitalOcean API URI and Endpoint URI
     *
     * i.e if $uri is set to 'domains', then $api ends up as
     *     $api = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains'
     */
    $uri = $api . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $uri;

    /**
     * Define Authorization and Content-Type Header.
     */
    $headers = "Authorization: Bearer $key \r\n" .
               "Content-Type: application/json";

    /**
     * If $data array is not empty, assume we're passing data, so we'll encode
     * it and pass it to 'content'. If $data is empty, assume we're not passing
     * data, so we won't sent 'content'.
     */
    if ( ! empty( $data ) )
    {
        $data = [
                    'http'          => [
                        'method'    =>  strtoupper( $method ),
                        'header'    =>  $headers,
                        'content'   =>  json_encode( $data )
                    ]
                ];
    }
    else
    {
        $data = [
                    'http'          => [
                        'method'    =>  strtoupper( $method ),
                        'header'    =>  $headers
                    ]
                ];
    }

    /**
     * Create Stream Context
     * http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
     */
    $context = stream_context_create( $data );

    /**
     * Send Request and Store to $response.
     */
    $response = file_get_contents( $uri, false, $context );

    /**
     * Return as decoded JSON (i.e. an array)
     */
    return json_decode( $response, true );
}

/**
 * Example Usage
 */

var_dump(doapi(
    'do-api-key',
    'get',
    'domains'
));
```

I used this to actually post the data successfully...

```
var_dump(doapi(
    $api_key,
    'post',
    'domains',
    array("name" => (string) $newDomain, "ip_address" => "1.2.3.4")
));
```

Comment: keep in mind... if you are adding domain records like CNAME or MX that reference other domain names there needs to be a dot `.` on the end of the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Content-Length` header and use `CURLOPT_POST` option for POST requests

```
function basic_api_handle($key, $method, $URI, $data) {
    $json = json_encode($data)
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URI);

    if ( $method === 'POST' ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        array_push($headers, 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json) );
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false) error_log("API ERROR: Connection failure: $URI", 0);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but I've tried that already and it makes no difference, nor does URL encoding or http_build_headers :(

Comment: You can also try use CURLOPT_POST

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
function basic_api_handle($key, $method, $URI, $data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method); // <-- Should be set to "GET" or "POST"
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // <-- Maybe the SSL is the problem

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"); // <-- I am not familiar with this API, but maybe it needs a user agent?
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$key,
        'Content-Type: application/json')
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URI);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); // <-- Add this line which counts the inputs you send
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false) error_log("API ERROR: Connection failure: $URI", 0);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

It can also be a problem of a header you should sent and your missing it.

Comment: CURLOPT_POST doesn't work the way you think it does. It's either 1/0 (true/false), on/off. Also, his post fields aren't http-encoded.

Comment: Turning off verify host and verify peer is very insecure.  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

Comment: Wrong - when you need to get the contents of a web page but you couldn't care less about it's authentication, this is what you have to do.

Comment: I do need to be concerned about authentication - I'll try the count idea...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a 307 or 308 http redirect.

Maybe "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains" redirects to another url.

If this is the case, try adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

to make curl follow the redirection and keep the parameters.
It is suggested that you also use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

to keep the request body.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your help, although I did try that :( didn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try use CURLOPT_POST